# How to keep my footer on the bottom of every page regardless if the page has content or not?

Tags: html, css, footer

Im using the default Web Application MVC project and if i dont have much content on the page the footer is going up. How can i make the footer to stay always on bottom of the page?

my html structure is this

```
<body>
  <div class="body-content"><div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific, as well as provide code examples. Read the help section of Stack Overflow to learn how to ask a proper question.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: declare a css rule with `bottom: 0px;` and choose position as fixed/absolute which satisfy your needs.

Comment: @marmeladze that will only put the footer on bottom of the viewport and when you scroll down the footer will stay up.

Comment: @ZackTanner That doesnt work for me also the footer is on the middle of page, and overlapping other elemnts

Comment: which one @MIle? fixed or absolute? or `bottom: 0px`?  or all together? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sticky footer</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<style>
html, body {
height: 100%;
background: #e4e4e4;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.main {
clear: both;
overflow: auto;
padding-bottom: 100px;
}
footer {
margin-top: -100px;
background-color: #1b1e25;
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="main">
<p>Some content</p>
</div>
</div>

<footer>
<p>footer</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Original source: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, i tried it and it`s exactly what i need.