# Let the footer down: is this CSS code correct?

Tags: html, css

I need the footer html elemenent to appear down the page (even when the content is not enough). I found a bounch of solutions by googling and all seemed to me to be more complicated than they should (stuff like creating #containers of #containers of..). Here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Footer</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Cinosarge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <p>THIS IS A HEADER - THIS IS A HEDER</p>
    </header>
    <section>
        <p>THIS IS A SECTION - THIS IS A SECTION</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>THIS IS A FOOTER - THIS IS A FOOTER</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the related css style:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body{
position:absolute;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

footer{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Now, this works fine for me but, is this piece of code correct? (in particular, is it a good idea to give the body element an absolute position? What kind of problems I could strumble into by using that css?

Thank you.

Comment: hi please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999440/how-to-keep-my-footer-on-the-bottom-of-every-page-regardless-if-the-page-has-con/33000149#33000149

Comment: This is a bad idea because you will have an overlap when the content is 100% height or more (see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jnL5o52b/), the footer overlaps with the content). A solution could be to give the body a bottom padding that has the same size as the height of the footer. However, this won't work on a dynamic height footer. Google *sticky footer* for the best ideas.